# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 with android-support-v4.jar

Tags: android, facebook, dalvik

I am trying add the facebook library to my Android project, a getting **Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1** error. After searching, it seems that my problem is related to the **android-support-v4.jar**.

Both the jar appears in the facebook dependencies and in the dependencies in my project. I deleted both jars and re-added one to the facebook library, but I still get the error. Below is a screen shot to show where the dependencies are.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If you are adding it to your facebook SDK library do not add it to the projects that are referencing the FacebookSDK. They will automatically inherit that jar file

Comment: I'm sorry I incorrectly explained myself. I didn't add the jar to the project - just deleted it. I updated my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a duplicated dependency issue.

Remove the last dependency on the NCC project

```
 android-support-v4.jar - /Users/Heather/Documents/workspace/facebook-android-sdk-3.0/facebook/libs
```

android-support-v4.jar is already provided by the FacebookSDK library project, therefore there's no need to reference it again on the main project

Comment: That dependency get added automatically when I set facebook to be a library dependency. Should I still remove it?

Comment: That's weird because i don't see the annotations.jar that is also included on the FacebookSDK library project. I would double check your project classpath, to ensure that you didn't manually added the support jar on your app project. Just to discard other options, Do you have a 'libs' folder inside your app project? Maybe you have a copy of the support jar in there.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too with an app that used Facebook SDK. I was trying all sorts of stuff, so I'm not sure what exactly fixed but here's settings that worked for me:

FacebookSDK > Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export

Android 2.2 - NOT CHECKED

Android Private Libraries - CHECKED

Android Dependencies - CHECKED

MyApp > Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export

Android 4.2.2 - CHECKED

Android Private Libraries - CHECKED

Android Dependencies - CHECKED

In addition, I had done this before, not sure it mattered. Reverted to Facebook SDK version 3.5 from 3.5.2. Updated to latest ADT 22.2.1. Changed Facebook SDK to use Android 2.2 from 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the error is caused due to the permissions also. Check if you have declared multiple permissions in your manifest file. Delete the extraneous permission from the file.

This worked for me :

this is a typical manifest file for facebookSDK based app

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.devey.androidnativeapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.devey.androidnativeapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.devey.androidnativeapp.Testnative"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_testnative" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I deleted this extra permission and clean build my app with no further errors :

> android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES"